# How to use variable to store error type for catch block?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I want to handle exceptions for every command in my script. To that end I'm writing a function for `try..catch`. This function has two parameters: `$command`, the command to be executed, and `$errorType`, the optional error type specified in the `catch` block.

```
function tryCatch ($command, $errorType) {
    try {
        $command
    } catch [$errorType] {
        # function to be called if this error type occurs
        catchError
    }
}
```

However I can't figure out how to pass the error type to the catch block as a variable. I get this error:

```
At \script.ps1:233 char:25
+         try {$command} catch [$errorType] {catchError}
+                               ~
Missing type name after '['.
```

I've tried to get around it but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, I don't believe you can do what you're trying. Lemme walkthrough just to make sure I understand the scenario.

The parameter for the `catch` block is one or more exception types like `System.Net.WebException`:

```
try {
   $wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
   $wc.DownloadFile("http://www.contoso.com/MyDoc.doc")
} catch [System.Net.WebException], [System.IO.IOException] {
    "Unable to download MyDoc.doc from http://www.contoso.com."
} catch {
    "An error occurred that could not be resolved."
}
```

Saying this just to level set.

Now, we typically see those types hard coded, but you'd like to assign the type in the catch block dynamically as a variable:

```
try {
   ...
} catch $exceptionType {
   catchError
}
```

The problem is catch needs to be followed by an exception type not a variable. That variable will be (if it hosts an exception type) of type RuntimeType. You can try to finagle the exception type out of the variable with GetType() or something like that. Net-net, it just won't work.

Put a generic catch block (with no type) in your script-function-whatever then pass the values to your catch function, and have the branching logic in there do whatever you're trying to do.

```
try { ... } catch { catchError -Command $command -Exception $_ }
```

And, if you don't want to pass the whole exception object, you can use...

```
$_.FullyQualifiedErrorId
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct in understanding what I'm trying to do. Thank you for the very helpful info and explaining exactly why what I'm trying to do won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a variable to specify a type to catch. What you can do is use a condition inside the `catch` block:

```
function Invoke-Something($command, [Object]$errorType) {
    try {
        $command
    } catch {
        if ($_.Exception -is $errorType) {
            catchError
        } else {
            # do something else
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Something 'whatever the command' ([System.IO.IOException])
```